# sql instead of update : trigger on specific columns

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have been wondering if there is a way to use an instead of update trigger to update and log specific columns while alowing the normal update of other columns

Comment: Maybe the best way in this case - computed columns...

Comment: use instead of trigger,this way you can always update specific column to a  choosen  value and rest you can insert from virtual tables,Further this doesnt have a cost of rolling back updated data

Comment: How could I do that? Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a DML trigger on a part of the table. The trigger is for the entire table.

You can, however, use an `instead of` trigger with whatever logic you want, and then update the table with the data directly from `inserted`.

a quick example:

```
create table myTable
(
    colId int identity(1,1),
    col1 int, 
    col2 varchar(10)
)
go

create trigger t_iou on myTable instead of update
as
     update t
     set col1 = i.col1,
         col2 = i.col2 + ' ('+ cast(i.col1 as varchar) +')'
     from myTable t
     inner join inserted i on(t.colId = i.colId)
go
```